# Laravel5 iis pseudo-static writing

Tags: iis

The following is how Nginx is written:

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;}
```

I want to get pseudo-static writing in iis environment，The same effect.
Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

you could try the below URL rewrite rule to implement your requirement:

```
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

make sure you have installed the iis URL rewrite module. if not you could download it from the below link:

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite